# Clear tr rows with ngFor variable

Tags: angular

My table tr is created dynamically like

```
<tr (click)="populateTransDtls(row);" *ngFor="let row of transRespJSON">
```

But after a while I wanted to clear tr that has been created. when I try to clear by setting variable value = "", it is not getting cleared.

```
this.transRespJSON = "";
```

Comment: How about `this.transRespJSON = []`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngFor works over array, you need to clear it using

```
this.transRespJSON = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because transRespJSON is an array you can't clear it like that.
You have to put `this.transRespJSON = []` to clear it